# Git merge conflict with unrelated file?

Tags: git, merge, conflict

I'm getting some really weird behavior in Git 1.7.5.4 when trying to merge from one older release branch of our software to the master.

```
$ git checkout master
$ git merge 0.1.2.3
[...]
Auto-merging ProjectA/src/main/groovy/com/example/package/Something.groovy
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in ProjectA/src/main/groovy/com/example/package/Something.groovy
[...]
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

Looking at that file, I see something really weird:

```
$ cat ProjectA/src/main/groovy/com/example/package/Something.groovy

<<<<<<< HEAD
[contents of ProjectA/src/main/groovy/com/example/package/Something.groovy]
=======
[contents of ProjectC/src/main/groovy/com/example/something/Different.groovy !!]
>>>>>>> 0.1.2.3
```

The `Something.groovy` file doesn't exist on the other branch.  The `Different.groovy` file doesn't exist anymore on the master branch.  I would have expected to have gotten a merge conflict warning about the file not existing.  I did not expect it to get incorrectly related to a completely unrelated file in a different project.

Any idea what could cause something like this? I don't think it's a hash collision, looking at the hashes of the history of the files using `git log --raw` and `git show --raw`.

Answer (score 0):

I would grab the latest version of git and try it again. The one you're using is over a year old.

Secondly, check if the file contents are similar. Git detects the move of a file based on the contents and will use it to help merge branches.

Comment: They're not similar at all. That version of git is the current one for Linux Mint, but I'll attempt to get a newer version.